# Issue in calculating the days from 2 dates difference

Tags: php

**Code**

```
$date1 = date('Y/m/d', strtotime("Oct 09 2018"));
$date2 = date('Y/m/d', strtotime("Sep 09 2018"));

$dateDiff = $date2 - $date1;

echo (round(($dateDiff)/ (60 * 60 * 24)));
```

It displays 0. Am I missing anything?

Comment: maybe not subtracting two strings might be a great starting point

Answer (score 1):

Date() returns a string value. You can just ditch it altogether if you are comparing dates:

```
$date1 = strtotime("Oct 09 2018");
$date2 = strtotime("Sep 09 2018");

$dateDiff = $date2 - $date1;

echo (round(($dateDiff)/ (60 * 60 * 24)));
```

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to subtract `$date2` from `$date1`, however, `date('Y/m/d', strtotime("Oct 09 2018"))` returns something like `2018/10/09`, you cant subtract those.

[`strtotime()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) returns an unix timestamp, perfect to subtract those to get the diff:

```php
<?php

$date1 = strtotime("Oct 09 2018");
$date2 = strtotime("Sep 09 2018");

$dateDiff = $date2 - $date1;

echo (round(($dateDiff)/ (60 * 60 * 24)));
```

Will ouput `-30` as you can see [in this online demo](https://tio.run/##K8go@P/fxr4go4CLSyUlsSTVUMFWobikqCS/JDM3VUPJP7lEwcBSwcjA0EJJ0xqixAhVSXBqAbISiBqXzLQ0oDKoel0IwxAom5qcka@gUZRfmpeioQFXqqmvoGFmoKClACaMTDQ1Na3//wcA).